# PHP - get decimal(16,4) equivalent of current date and time

Tags: php

I want to get the `decimal(16,4)` value of the current date and time in PHP.

For example what would be the `decimal(16,4)` equivalent of `2022-08-10 12:50:00`.

I tried the following but its not working:

```
$gmtTimezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw');
$myDateTime = new DateTime('now', $gmtTimezone);
$time = $myDateTime->format('U');
```

P.S. - The reason I want this value is so I can compare it to the `decimal(16,4)` value `1389639800.8659` saved in database.

Comment: Databases do have datetime and timestamp fields. No need to do that.

Comment: Database i am working with has date and time saved in the decimal(16,4) format, I do not have the option to change that.

Comment: Please let me know, what database is it? Or do you mean you are forced to use a special table format?

Comment: Its a MySQL database, and this was created by previous developers and I do not have the option of changing that. They are saving the date and time in decimal(16,4) data type of MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method to bring the output to your like.

```
$gmtTimezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw');
$myDateTime = new DateTime('now', $gmtTimezone);
$time = $myDateTime->format('U.u');
$decimal = sprintf('%12.4f', $time);
echo $decimal;
```

```
1660118259.1626
```

Comment: @ILG Unix time for `2022-08-10 12:50:00 Europe/Warsaw` is not `1389639800.8659` but `1660128600`.  If this works for you, sample data in the question can't be right. 

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I don't think you read the question correctly. `1389639800.8659` is a value I needed to compare with, I never said that it equates to `2022-08-10 12:50:00 Europe/Warsaw`. Markus Zeller's answer solved the problem indeed.

Comment: @ILG The point is that there're lots of different ways to map integers to dates. If you don't have any known value to compare with, it's just guessing. Is "280" a hot or a cold temperature? It depends if it's Celsius or kelvin. `20220812` can be Unix time 23 Aug 1970 00:53:32 UTC... or today.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the timestamp given as `decimal(16,4)` is seconds since epoch before the decimal-point, and fractions of a second after it, the nearest you can get to that functionality, limited to `now` as in your example code, is `microtime(true)`.

A `psysh` session as example

```
Psy Shell v0.11.5 (PHP 8.1.8 — cli) by Justin Hileman
New version is available (current: v0.11.5, latest: v0.11.8)
>>> microtime(true);
=> 1660117557.3622

>>>|
```

But, as Martin Zeller wrote in his comment, it would be better to use a date-time column type of the database in use.  And if this is a solution to your problem at hand depends on context not given in the question.

For dates other than now, see Martins answer and use `format`.